# Puppeteer: correct way to detect and access popup opened in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to open up muliple popups and access each one of them.

Below is the relevant part of code i am using.

```
    const newPagePromise = new Promise(res => browser.on('targetcreated', target => res(target.page())));
    for(const dataWorkSheet of dataWorkSheetsArray) {
        await page.evaluate(async () => {
          await $('#myDataExport').click();
          await $('.export a').click();
        });
        await page.waitFor(3000);
        const exportPopup = await newPagePromise;
    }
```

should `newPagePromise` be outside the `for`? would it work for all the popups i am opening?

Any help in clarifying this would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: As written, `newPagePromise` is resolved just a single time, no matter how many loop iterations there are. The promise needs to be created each time you want to wait for it.

Comment: @tehhowch, if i put the `newPagePromise` the code just hangs and does not proceed further

Answer (score 1):

I would keep count of the popups you need and then await for that:

```js
// keep track for targets
let targets = [];

// we create a promise with a callback to resolve the promis
let resolve;
const popupPromise = new Promise(x => resolve = x);

browser.on('targetcreated', target => {
    // Collect popups
    targets.push(target.page());
    // If we got all popups we resolve this
    if(targets.length == dataWorkSheetsArray)
        resolve();
});

for(const dataWorkSheet of dataWorkSheetsArray) {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await $('#myDataExport').click();
        await $('.export a').click();
    });
    await page.waitFor(3000);
}
//Wait for the promise to be resolved
await popupPromise;
//Do something with the popups
console.log(targets);
```